# How to get all possible combinations of substrings?

Tags: java, string, algorithm, combinations

I have a String of following structure:
A1(N1,N2,N3)P4(O3,O5)Y1.

How to get all combinations? The rule is that options inside parenthesis should not go together. For this example the output should be:

```
A1N1P4O3Y1,
A1N2P4O3Y1,
A1N3P4O3Y1,
A1N1P4O5Y1,
A1N2P4O5Y1,
A1N3P4O5Y1.
```

There can be parenthesis, but it can be without it. Another example:

N3P5(L1,L2)Q1, output should be:

```
N3P5L1Q1,
N3P5L2Q1.
```

Anyone with elegant solution?

Comment: Break your problem into pieces.  Figure out how to read the input and model it with a List of Lists.  Figure out how to process the List of Lists into all the outputs.

Comment: Maroun, I need this really fast, I know I can do it in a couple of hours but I have production in 3 days and that's why I asked for a solution... Thanks anyway...

Comment: @DjordjeIvanovic Stack Overflow is not a source of free programming for when you don't have time to do it yourself. Offloading your job to this site is not appropriate or allowed

Answer (score 0):

The main idea is to transform a string input into a StringTemplate that holds parts, that can be a single string or a group of strings.

For each part, a iterator is created. While some iterator can go next, update a string array that holds current part values and reset all iterators of parts that come before the part that changed. Feel free to clear repeated code and add nested groups support and syntax verifications if needed.

```
private static StringTemplate parse(String string) {

    List<StringPart> parts = new ArrayList<StringPart>();

    boolean insideGroup = false;
    StringBuilder currentToken = new StringBuilder();

    List<LiteralPart> groupParts = new ArrayList<LiteralPart>();

    for (int i = 0; i < string.length(); i++) {
        char ch = string.charAt(i);

        if (ch == '(') {

            if (currentToken.length() != 0) {
                parts.add(new LiteralPart(currentToken.toString()));
                currentToken.delete(0, currentToken.length());
            }

            insideGroup = true;

        } else if (ch == ')') {

            if (insideGroup) {

                if (currentToken.length() != 0) {
                    groupParts.add(new LiteralPart(currentToken.toString()));
                    currentToken.delete(0, currentToken.length());
                }

                parts.add(new CompositePart(groupParts));
                groupParts.clear();
                insideGroup = false;

            } else {
                currentToken.append(ch);
            }

        } else if (ch == ',') {

            if (insideGroup) {

                if (currentToken.length() != 0) {
                    groupParts.add(new LiteralPart(currentToken.toString()));
                    currentToken.delete(0, currentToken.length());
                }

            } else {
                currentToken.append(ch);
            }

        } else {
            currentToken.append(ch);
        }
    }

    if (currentToken.length() != 0) {
        parts.add(new LiteralPart(currentToken.toString()));
        currentToken.delete(0, currentToken.length());
    }

    return new StringTemplate(parts);

}

private static final class StringTemplate {

    private final List<StringPart> parts;

    public StringTemplate(List<StringPart> parts) {
        this.parts = parts;
    }

    public List<String> getCombinations() {
        List<Iterator<String>> iterators = new ArrayList<Iterator<String>>(parts.size()); 

        for (StringPart part : parts) {
            iterators.add(part.getStrings().iterator());
        }

        String[] toJoin = new String[iterators.size()];

        List<String> combinations = new ArrayList<String>();
        int iteratorThatAdvanced;
        int maxIteratorThatAdvanced = Integer.MIN_VALUE;
        boolean first = true;

        for (;;) {

            iteratorThatAdvanced = -1;

            for (int i = 0; i < iterators.size(); i++) {
                Iterator<String> iterator = iterators.get(i);

                if (first || iterator.hasNext()) {
                    String value = iterator.next();
                    toJoin[i] = value;

                    iteratorThatAdvanced = i;

                    if (!first && i >= maxIteratorThatAdvanced) {
                        maxIteratorThatAdvanced = i;
                        break;
                    }
                }
            }

            if (iteratorThatAdvanced < 0) {
                break;
            }

            if (!first) {
                for (int i = 0; i < iteratorThatAdvanced; i++) {
                    Iterator<String> iterator = parts.get(i).getStrings().iterator();
                    iterators.set(i, iterator);
                    toJoin[i] = iterator.next();
                }
            }

            combinations.add(join(toJoin));
            first = false;

        }

        return combinations;
    }

}

private static String join(String[] strings) {
    StringBuilder builder = new StringBuilder();
    for (String string : strings) {
        builder.append(string);
    }
    return builder.toString();
}

private static abstract class StringPart {

    abstract List<String> getStrings();

}

private static final class LiteralPart extends StringPart {

    private final String literal;

    public LiteralPart(String literal) {
        this.literal = literal;
    }

    @Override
    List<String> getStrings() {
        return Collections.singletonList(literal);
    }

}

private static final class CompositePart extends StringPart {

    private final List<LiteralPart> parts;

    public CompositePart(List<LiteralPart> parts) {
        this.parts = new ArrayList<LiteralPart>(parts);
    }

    @Override
    List<String> getStrings() {
        List<String> strings = new ArrayList<String>(parts.size());

        for (LiteralPart part : parts) {
            strings.add(part.literal);
        }

        return strings;
    }

}
```

Example:

```
public static void main(String[] args) {
    StringTemplate template = parse("A1(N1,N2,N3)P4(O3,O5)Y1");

    for (String combination : template.getCombinations()) {
        System.out.println(combination);
    }

    template = parse("N3P5(L1,L2)Q1");

    for (String combination : template.getCombinations()) {
        System.out.println(combination);
    }
}
```